# Reactjs boostrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am learning React and I have some trouble with using the bootstrap grid/reactstrap. Somehow when I use the grid system, instead of aligning horizontal columns, I got a vertical one.

**Film.js**

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./ghibli.png";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody,
  CardTitle, CardSubtitle, Button } from 'reactstrap';

const Films = props => (
  <Container>
    <Row>
      <Col md= "3">
      <Card>
        <CardImg top width="100%" src={logo} alt="Card image cap" />
        <CardBody>
          <CardTitle>{props.title}</CardTitle>
          <CardSubtitle>{props.director}</CardSubtitle>
          <CardText>{props.description}</CardText>
          <Button>Button</Button>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Container>
);

export default Films;
```

Comment: You've only got one `Col` in `Film.js`, so it won't create several horizontal columns. What exactly were you expecting?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. I forgot to add my App.js when I post this.  I'm Mapping to an array from an API. I fixed it already by adding the col to the return of my App.js

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you only have one column (`col`) in a row.

As soon as you add more than column into a row, they'll start showing up side by side i.e. horizontally.

I have no clue about reactjs but I suspect that the following code will probably do the trick and produce 2 columns in a row:

```html
const Films = props => (
<Container>
    <Row>
        <Col md= "3">
            <Card>
                <CardImg top width="100%" src={logo} alt="Card image cap" />
                <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle>{props.title}</CardTitle>
                    <CardSubtitle>{props.director}</CardSubtitle>
                    <CardText>{props.description}</CardText>
                    <Button>Button</Button>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col md= "3">
            <Card>
                <CardImg top width="100%" src={logo} alt="Card image cap" />
                <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle>{props.title}</CardTitle>
                    <CardSubtitle>{props.director}</CardSubtitle>
                    <CardText>{props.description}</CardText>
                    <Button>Button</Button>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        </Col>
    </Row>
</Container>
);
```